# CUDO miner installation on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, dependencies, configuration

I am looking for assistance to solve the following issue while trying to install CUDO miner (a cryptocurrency miner. I am trying to install it from the command line.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
Architecture:   amd64
```

1. I am running:

   ```
   sudo su -c "bash <( wget -qO- https://download.cudo.org/tenants/135790374f46b0107c516a5f5e13069b/5e5f800fdf87209fdf8f9b61441e53a1/linux/x64/stable/install.sh )"
   ```
2. Questions poped up, and they are answered,
3. After the last question, this is the message I got:

   ```
   dpkg: error processing package cudo-miner-service (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cudo-miner-headless:
    cudo-miner-headless depends on cudo-miner-service (= 1.1.4); however:
     Package cudo-miner-service is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package cudo-miner-headless (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                             Errors were encountered while processing:
    cudo-miner-service
    cudo-miner-headless
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
   ```
4. To solved I have:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge cudo-miner-headless
   sudo apt-get purge cudo-miner-service
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```

Comment: After the first error just configure the package ```cudo-miner-service``` manually via ```sudo dpkg --configure cudo-miner-service```.